# Lost focus in browser when using clipboard for search query [autohotkey]

Tags: autohotkey, waterfox

I am using a simple script to run a google/wikipedia/etc search using a hotkey, unfortunately after the search result appears in a new tab, I have to click because the tab is not on focus, although the browser windows is on focus. I tried to add a WinActivate but it's not working. This script used to work as expected before a new OS installation. Why is this script making lose focus on the browser?

Here's the script

```
^+g:: 
{
Send, ^c
sleep 200
Run, https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%Clipboard% 
sleep 50
WinActivate, ahk_exe waterfox.exe
}
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but it looks like increasing the delay between the Run and the WinActivate seems to fix it.

```
^+g:: 
{
Send, ^c
sleep 200
Run, https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%Clipboard% 
sleep 500 ;Up from 50, you might be able to fine-tune this number based on your computer's speed
WinActivate, ahk_exe waterfox.exe
}
```

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem, however I still find it puzzling that WinActivate was never needed in this kind of script, as you can also see in the autohotkey forum.

Comment: Yeah, @HermanToothrot, I had to install the Waterfox web browser in order to test this and it looks like it doesn't like to make itself the active window upon launch (which I would think might be good for automating some sort of web-based task in the background)

Comment: Thank you for checking that, so it looks like it's a Waterfox-related behavior.